# Is a settimeout function considered an interger JavaScript

Tags: javascript, timeout, settimeout

I am attempting to debug a program and I want to know what a "setTimeout" function should be considered in the code below.

```
var timeOut = setTimeout(function(){
   alert("hi");
}, 2000);
// console.log(timeOut);
```

If I paste those exact lines of code into my program the console reads nothing but an integer (in my case the number 2).

If I put the code in a for loop the "timeOut" variable increments, starting with 2, then 3 and so on.

Is this expected behavior?

The main thing I wanted to debug is if I try to clear the timeout like so

```
"clearTimeout(timeOut);"
```

It fails to clear, and the alert still fires. However I can't find anything in my code that would cause this, and if I change variable names to avoid and possible confliction I missed it's still the same behavior.

So my question is do setTimeout functions return an integer by default, and what possible things could I search for that would be triggering behavior like this.

Comment: See https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, `timeOut` in your snippet above is a number--an id for the timeout event so that you can then clear it if you want to.  (It is different on the server side, where, with node.js setTimeout returns an object, but the effect and usage are the same.)

This code will clear the timeout:

```
var timeOut = setTimeout(function(){
   alert("hi");
}, 2000);
clearTimeout(timeOut);
```

If your timeout is not getting cleared, it must be that you have the wrong id, or you have cleared it too late.